# MS Access combining data from multiple rows into one

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a access db that have this kind of data and I would like to write a query that will output the combined rows. I have looked into joins and other things but don't really grasp how they can do what I want.

```
Person   Company    Item1   Item2  Item3  
1        A          5         
2        A                  3
3        A                         4
4        B          3            
5        B                  2
6        B                         1
```

Combine it to

```
Company       Item1   Item2   Item3
A             5       3       4
B             3       2       1
```

It is supposed to be only one Item1 per Company and I realize there might be an issue if I have double. But that is another problem.

Comment: What do the numbers for "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" represent? Are they quantities or something else that should/could be summed together?

Comment: As your second solution do, they are not supposed to to be summed but rather just take the first available non null value. I know it sounds crazy but suming them up will not create the result I was looking fo. Superthanks for the answer. I could not be happier.

Comment: No problem.  :)  Glad it has helped you out. Make sure you mark it as being the answer to help out other people in the future!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, there definitely could be issues if there are more of each item for a single company, but that could be more of a database design issue, so let's not go into that!  :)

### Totaling/summing the item values

If the numbers under "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", etc are meant to be totaled/summed together, then you have a nice easy query on your hands:

```
SELECT Company, Sum(Item1) AS Item1Total, Sum(Item2) AS Item2Total, Sum(Item3) AS Item3Total
FROM test
GROUP BY Company;
```

### Finding the first non-NULL item value

If you need to find the first non-NULL value for each item, then your query is going to be a little bit more complex. This example uses sub-queries to find the first non-NULL entry for each item column/field for the current company:

```
SELECT t0.Company, (
    SELECT TOP 1 t1.Item1
    FROM test AS t1
    WHERE t1.Company = t0.Company
    AND t1.Item1 IS NOT NULL
) AS Item1Total, (
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.Item2
    FROM test AS t2
    WHERE t2.Company = t0.Company
    AND t2.Item2 IS NOT NULL
) AS Item2Total, (
    SELECT TOP 1 t3.Item3
    FROM test AS t3
    WHERE t3.Company = t0.Company
    AND t3.Item3 IS NOT NULL
) AS Item3Total
FROM test AS t0
GROUP BY Company;
```